# Perl error: can't call method "encpass" on an undefined value - WHY?

Tags: perl, perl-module

What is the problem with the following code as "root" user:

**chpwd.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Unix::PasswdFile;

use strict;
use warnings;

$pw = new Unix::PasswdFile "/etc/passwd";
$pw->passwd("johndoe", $pw->encpass("newpass"));
$pw->commit();
undef $pw;
```

Whenever I try to execute the above script, I get the following error:

> Can't call method "encpass" on an undefined value at /var/www/chpwd.pl line 5

I confirm the file `/etc/passwd` is not empty or symbolic link, it has ownership of

> rw-r--r-- root:root 1022 passwd

User `johndoe` do exist in the system.

Please help. Thanks.

Trace Output (partial):

```
Unix::ConfigFile::mode(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:152):
152:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::mode(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:153):
153:        return $this->{mode} unless @_;
Unix::ConfigFile::new(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:64):
64:     $this->lock() or return undef;
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:165):
165:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:167):
167:        return 1 if ($this->locking eq "none");
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:127):
127:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:129):
129:        return $this->{locking} unless @_;
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:168):
168:        return 0 if $this->{locked};
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:169):
169:        if ($this->locking eq "flock") {
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:127):
127:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:129):
129:        return $this->{locking} unless @_;
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:127):
127:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:129):
129:        return $this->{locking} unless @_;
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:174):
174:        my $fh = new IO::File $this->lockfile, O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR;
Unix::ConfigFile::lockfile(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:145):
145:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::lockfile(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:146):
146:        @_ ? $this->{lockfile} = shift : $this->{lockfile};
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:35):
35:     my $type = shift;
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:36):
36:     my $class = ref($type) || $type || "IO::File";
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:37):
37:     @_ >= 0 && @_ <= 3
38:     or croak "usage: new $class [FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]]]";
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:39):
39:     my $fh = $class->SUPER::new();
IO::Handle::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm:54):
54:     my $class = ref($_[0]) || $_[0] || "IO::Handle";
IO::Handle::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm:55):
55:     @_ == 1 or croak "usage: new $class";
IO::Handle::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm:56):
56:     my $io = gensym;
Symbol::gensym(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Symbol.pm:23):
23:     my $name = "GEN" . $genseq++;
Symbol::gensym(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Symbol.pm:24):
24:     my $ref = \*{$genpkg . $name};
Symbol::gensym(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Symbol.pm:24):
24:     my $ref = \*{$genpkg . $name};
Symbol::gensym(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Symbol.pm:25):
25:     delete $$genpkg{$name};
Symbol::gensym(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Symbol.pm:26):
26:     $ref;
IO::Handle::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm:57):
57:     bless $io, $class;
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:40):
40:     if (@_) {
IO::File::new(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:41):
41:     $fh->open(@_)
42:         or return undef;
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:52):
52:     @_ >= 2 && @_ <= 4 or croak 'usage: $fh->open(FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]])';
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:53):
53:     my ($fh, $file) = @_;
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:54):
54:     if (@_ > 2) {
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:55):
55:     my ($mode, $perms) = @_[2, 3];
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:56):
56:     if ($mode =~ /^\d+$/) {
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:57):
57:         defined $perms or $perms = 0666;
IO::File::open(/usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/File.pm:58):
58:         return sysopen($fh, $file, $mode, $perms);
Unix::ConfigFile::lock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:175):
175:        return 0 unless defined($fh);
Unix::ConfigFile::new(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:104):
104:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::new(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:106):
106:        $this->unlock() or croak "Can't unlock file: $!";
Unix::ConfigFile::unlock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:184):
184:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::unlock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:193):
193:        return 1 if ($this->locking eq "none");
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:127):
127:        my $this = shift;
Unix::ConfigFile::locking(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:129):
129:        return $this->{locking} unless @_;
Unix::ConfigFile::unlock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:194):
194:        return 0 unless $this->{locked};
Carp::croak(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp.pm:44):
44: sub croak   { die  shortmess @_ }
Carp::shortmess(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp.pm:29):
29: sub shortmess { goto &shortmess_jmp }
Carp::shortmess_real(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp/Heavy.pm:51):
51:     local @CARP_NOT = caller();
Carp::shortmess_real(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp/Heavy.pm:52):
52:     shortmess_heavy(@_);
Carp::shortmess_heavy(/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp/Heavy.pm:241):
241:      return longmess_heavy(@_) if $Verbose;
```

**UPDATE:**

The above script runs perfectly on my local machine not in server machine.

Comment: With what user are you executing the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Always. Do this, and you may discover errors you did not notice before.

It appears that `$pw` is uninitialized, which would imply that the `new` declaration has failed. However, it would seem unlikely that it did, since you should have an `/etc/passwd` file, and as root you should be able to read it. You can easily check for this with:

```
die "Failed to read PW" unless (defined $pw);
```

Is "johndoe" an existing user? If not, I suspect the method `passwd` would fail.

ETA: Since the trace shows an error with locking, perhaps the file is being used by another process, and therefore can't be locked/unlocked?

Comment: You are correct, I get the "die" message. What should I do? Since, Unix::PasswdFile is library file, I am not sure how should move further.

Comment: I have added a trace output in the question, please see. I am not where the flow is getting failed, but the exception happens at this line in ConfigFile.pm `Unix::ConfigFile::unlock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:194):
194:     return 0 unless $this->{locked};`

Comment: @Rakesh `0` is defined, though, so it would not trigger `unless (defined $pw)`. That does not fit with your error about an undefined value, nor the `die` statement.

Comment: @Rakesh hmm, well, nevermind. Your problem lies with the `new` statement. Have you tried adding `use strict; use warnings;` yet? If not, do so. Check `/etc/passwd`, see that nothing is wrong with it. If it is empty or does not exist or is a symbolic link, I imagine that might cause some problems.

Comment: @TLP I did add `use strict; use warnings;` but vain. Looking at the ownership of `/etc/passwd` it reads `rw-r-r root:root` that means it should able to read by all & write only by `root`. BTW, I am running this script by `root` user. The same script works perfect in the local machine as a `root` user. Will there be explicit function that is blocking perl to read this file?

Comment: @Rakesh did you check that the file is not empty? And not a symbolic link? I don't know if that is possible, but the error can only be on that line, so it must be something. Update your question to show that you use strict and warnings, so other users will not remark on it. Also, if any new errors show up, write them in as well. Show everything.

Comment: @Rakesh Try copying `/etc/passwd` to another location and opening that file instead, e.g. `/tmp/pwdcopy`.

Comment: @TLP Updated the code. Yes I confirm `/etc/passwd` is not a symbolic link or empty.

Comment: @Rakesh Oh wait a sec... the error is about the locking. Do you have another process running that has a lock on that file?

Comment: @TLP Oh yes, there could be lots of chances. Since, it is a system file used by Linux for maintaining the passwords of it's users.

Comment: @Rakesh Well, I'm out of ideas. Try copying the `/etc/passwd` from the local machine (where it works) to a temp file and open that. Try using the options for `new`, such as `locking => "none"`.

Comment: @TLP okay. Good. Thanks, let me try these and figure out the solution. Thanks for pointing out to a good direction.

Comment: @Rakesh did you figure out the problem?

Comment: @TLP Yes, the file was being used by another process (like I said it is one of the system file and it was open by another process).

Comment: @Rakesh Cool, glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the constructor returns `undef` rather than the newly created object. Here is a piece of the source of the constructor (in `ConfigFile.pm`):

```
# Get a filehandle
my $fh = new IO::File $this->filename, $this->mode;
return undef unless defined($fh);
$this->fh($fh);

# Do file locking - this must happen before read is called or we could
# end up with stale data in memory
if ($this->mode eq "r") {
  $this->lock("shared") or return undef;
}
else {
  $this->lock() or return undef;
}

# Initialize object structure from the file
if (exists $opt{readopts}) {
  $this->read($this->fh, $opt{readopts}) or return undef;
}
else {
  $this->read($this->fh) or return undef;
}
return $this;
```

You can trace it for yourself and see in which branch it goes.

Comment: this is far from my understanding on Perl. I found the above code from the CPAN and trying to run, but facing that error. Are you saying I should add/modify ConfigFile.pm somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can print tracing messages in `ConfigFile.pm` (this is where the constructor is located) and see which is the condition that fails.

Comment: There's really no need to edit ConfigFile.pm. It's probably easier to trace through the execution of the program using the Perl debugger - making sure to step into the call to Unix::PasswdFile->new.

Comment: @davorg can be more specific? I am a beginner to Perl and I have no clue on debugging perl script.

Comment: @davorg & @Blagovest please see the added trace-output for Unix::PasswdFile, it looks like it's failing at the line in ConfigFile.pm `Unix::ConfigFile::unlock(/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Unix/ConfigFile.pm:194):
194:     return 0 unless $this->{locked};`